# How to set color `rightBarButtonItem` on navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to set color of "Done" button on navigation bar like this image:

[image]

Although, I've set code as `self.doneButton.enabled = NO;` but Done button still has a white color. It does not change color like image.

How to set the code to change text color done button like Done button in the image above?
Please help me to solve this problem. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What font you are using? o_O

Answer (score 11):

for change the color of barbutton use

**objective C**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourRightbarbuttonName;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // add your color
```

**Swift**

or set from Story board
[image: Set bat button color]

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourRightbarbuttonName
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

if you want to **show the Right barbutton** use

**objective C**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
```

**Swift**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = true
```

if you want to **hide the Right barbutton** use

**objective C**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

**Swift**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 4):

For updated the colour for text of right bar item, we should use "setTitleTextAttributes"(swift 5). Please try this :

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "your text", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
rightBarButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black], for: .normal)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

Comment: I was here 9 Nov 2020 to uptick this. I'm back again today because I forgot again..... why can't tintColor just work for UIBarButtonItem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following line after disabling the button may help (not tested though)

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(editProfileClick)];
rightBarButton.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;


-(void)editProfileClick
{
//your methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it from XIB/Storyboard like shown in image[image: Set bar button color]

or you can set the property - tintColor of your barbutton item.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for support me. I also change the code like you but text color of "Done" button can not change. Now, I've found a good solution for this issue.

Firstly, I create a common function like that:

```
- (void)changeStatusOfRightBarButton:(BOOL)enabled withColorAlpha:(CGFloat)numberAlpha {
    _doneButton.enabled = enabled;
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]
    setTitleTextAttributes:
    @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"FFFFFF" alpha:numberAlpha],
    NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontAvenirNextRegularWithSize:15.0f]
    }
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

and secondly I apply it into `viewDidload` like that:

```
if (self.noteTextView.text.length == 0) {
    [self.noteTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    [self changeStatusOfRightBarButton:NO withColorAlpha:0.44f];
```

}

When I apply these code "Done" button has changed color.