# UIBarButtonItem programmatically change color

Tags: swift, swift5, xcode11

I have this left UIBarButtonItem that performs like a switch, so I would like to make it gray when its off and the normal tint color when its on but I can't figure out how

**Here is the code used to assign the buttons:**

```
    doneHomeworksButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: doneHomeworksButtonImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneHomeworksClicked))
    addButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: plusButtonImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(plusButtonClicked))

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneHomeworksButton
```

**This is the simulator** (I want to change the left button)
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set color \`rightBarButtonItem\` on navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864567/how-to-set-color-rightbarbuttonitem-on-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way, I use text instead of icon. you can user FM symbols of fontawesome or any other. And also you can change the image when button click

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{


var btnTick:UIBarButtonItem?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    btnTick  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "2", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didClickedBtn(_ :)))
    btnTick?.tintColor = .blue
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnTick
}

@objc func didClickedBtn(_ sender : UIBarButtonItem){
    sender.tintColor = .red
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

}

[image]

[image]